# Anyconnect VPN access slow for far away users

Tags: remote-access, cisco-vpn

We have our data on a Windows Server 2008 r2 Datacenter, we're using a Cisco ASA 5510, and my staff uses AnyConnect Mobility Client to get on our VPN to access our data.

This works well for us when we're on a good internet connection, not far from our office in NYC.  But occasionally our staff travels far - east Europe, Asia, India, and they report slow VPN access.  Our Cisco tech found that when they ping our servers here, the time ranges in the hundreds of ms.  He says that even though their internet connection may be good, the physical distance to our server, and the large number of hops their data has to take, make the VPN slow for them.

Does this make sense?  If so, is there a better solution?

Many thanks!
Matthew

Comment: `Does this make sense?` - Yes. `If so, is there a better solution?` - No. You can't do anything about the connection between the client and the server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the validation, that is logical.  If it's not too big a question, what do other small business use for situations like this?  Move everything into a cloud server/service? Or a syncing service, like dropbox or owncloud?  Thanks again!